# Unable to fetch

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, clearcase

I have a ccnet.config file which is shown below the initial 
part.I have a clear case installed.Now since my ccnet checks for 
modifications and when it finds some modifications,it should fetch 
that source code but thats not happening.

How am i supposed to fetch those source code to my local 
machine.ThreePartition is the build concerned which is supposed to be 
fetched. I guess my below code just checks for modifications in my vob object??Am i supposed to add any more tags so that ccnet fetches the latest source code from the clear case.?

```
            <project name="VSAT"> 


            <sourcecontrol type="clearCase"> 
                       <viewPath>W:\Test_Project\Installation\VSAT\ThreePartition</viewPath> 
                <branch>main</branch> 
                <autoGetSource>false</autoGetSource> 
                <useLabel>false</useLabel> 
                <useBaseline>false</useBaseline> 
                <projectVobName>Test_Project</projectVobName> 
                <viewName>MYView_view_test</viewName> 
                <executable>C:\atria\ClearCase\bin\cleartool.exe</executable> 
                <timeout>600000</timeout> 
            </sourcecontrol>
```

Thanks 
Maddy

Answer (score 1):

You might try `<autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>`.